# How to find number of days from given days?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two dates and want to find number of days including both dates, I tried something like this:

```
select datediff("d", '10/11/2012', '10/12/2012')
```

It is showing 1, but I want the result as 2 because we have 2 days 11 and 12.

Answer (score 9):

The latest version of SQL introduced support for adding integers!  Yay.

```
select datediff("d", '10/11/2012', '10/12/2012') + 1
                                                ^^^^^
```

Comment: oh no, I'm stuck with SQL 2005! I guess I still need to do `CASE x WHEN 1 THEN 2 WHEN 2 THEN 3 ...`

Answer (score 1):

Well datediff will always find the difference between 2 days, as you've noted, for your example, this is 1.  if you wanted to make this inclusive, then why not just +1 to the result?

```
select datediff("d", '10/11/2012', '10/12/2012') + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are also operating with negative differences, adding 1 may not give you the answer you are looking for, you can handle those situations like this:

```
declare @from datetime = '2012-10-11'
declare @to   datetime = '2012-10-10'

select datediff(day, @from, @to) 
 + case when datediff(day, @from, @to) < 0 then -1 else 1 end
```